# How to reformat date to YYYYMMDD using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where the date column is in string format yyyy-mm-dd. How would I remove the dashes so I'm left with yyyymmdd?

Comment: `=DATEVALUE(A1)` - then apply `yyyymmdd` number formatting.

Answer (score 5):

Either:

```
Range("A:A").Replace "-", ""
```

or

```
Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
```

The difference is if the dates are text that look like dates than use the first.  If the dates are true dates then use the second.